# All available currencies in Flutter

Tags: flutter, currency

I would like to get a list of all available currencies.

- For Android, such a list can be obtained like this:
  [Get All Possible Available Currencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536968/get-all-possible-available-currencies)
- For iOS like this:
  [Get list of supported currencies in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935404/get-list-of-supported-currencies-in-ios)

**And how to get it in Flutter?**

*I would like to display a list of all available currencies (name, code, symbol). Moreover, it is necessary that this currency names be in the desired language:*

[image]
[image]

Comment: This would be a perfect use of a plugin, using method channels. See https://docs.flutter.dev/packages-and-plugins/using-packages

Comment: Try this one: https://pub.dev/documentation/kind/latest/kind/Currency-class.html

Comment: @Szymson, thank you. This package does provide a good list of currencies. The only problem is that the currency names are not localized into other languages (English only).

Answer (score 2):

Somehow, I got a JSON file of country currency details. It has information on 115 currencies. I believe we have almost all country currencies in it. So, I'm providing you two files: one is the main file where you can see the UI for it & the other has a map in which you can see all of the currencies.

main.dart

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "package:myapp/currencies.dart";

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: "My App",
      home: HomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int? selectedIndex;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView.separated(
          itemCount: currencies.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            final Map<String, dynamic> currency = currencies[index];
            return ListTile(
              dense: true,
              leading: CircleAvatar(child: Text("${currency["symbol"]}")),
              title: Text("Name: ${currency["name"]}"),
              subtitle: Text("Code: ${currency["code"]}"),
              trailing: selectedIndex == index ? const Icon(Icons.check) : null,
              onTap: () {
                selectedIndex = selectedIndex != index ? index : null;
                setState(() {});
              },
            );
          },
          separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return const Divider(height: 1, thickness: 1);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

currencies.dart [View](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dharambudh1/619b9168421606ac7447ee3698463613/raw/b96099d7f57dfcfed981e8ba19c8ee7392c1dfad/currencies.dart)

This file has 1500 lines. I can't copy-paste it here, so I provide a Git Gist.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Nice file with a list of currencies. Unfortunately, the names of the currencies are only in English. Have you somehow resolved the localization issue? For example, to show a list in German to a user from Germany (that is, in accordance with the localization of the application).

Comment: The localization part is dense. Either you require the whole localized file or individual localized strings.

Comment: When developing natively, Android/iOS returns already localized strings (depending on the locale of the app). In this case, there is no need to translate anything manually. I'm wondering if there is any package to receive this data directly from iOS/Android.